# What's the difference between -c opt and --config=opt when building TensorFlow from source?

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

When building TensorFlow from source, we're asked to set `--config=opt` (which by default will enable the gcc flag `-march=native`) but across the web I see a lot of people using `-c opt` instead, but according to Bazel's documentation `-c` is actually shorthand for `--compilation_mode` and not `--config`!

Confusingly, `--compilation_mode` also takes 'opt' as a value, but I assume that's just coincidental? Could someone clarify the difference between `-c opt` and `--config=opt` when executing `bazel build` during TensorFlow compilation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `-c opt` flag is for telling Bazel to build with optimization settings enabled and no debug information. Like you mentioned `--compilation_mode opt`. This is related to the flags used to compile any code.

The `--config=opt` is telling Bazel, to look in the `.bazelrc` file during compilation and read any settings that match the `opt` configuration. After you run your `configure` script with tensorflow, you should have a `.bazelrc` file sitting in the root of your workspace which defines settings for multiple configurations. For the `opt` configuration, it adds the extra `-march-native` for compilation.

So it is a bit coincidental that they are named the same way. But `--config` is a flexible tool to choose Bazel settings from a `.bazelrc` file. `-c` is really just for building code with optimizations.

Comment: in addition to a `.bazelrc` file at the root of the workspace, there are other locations on disk where such a file may reside: https://bazel.build/designs/2016/06/21/environment.html#list-of-rc-files-read-by-bazel

Answer (score 5):

`--config` set a configuration that expands in a set of flag defined in a .rc file. E.g. if the rc file contains `build:opt -c opt`, setting `--config opt` on the command line will expand to `-c opt`. The tensorflow rc file [set `-c opt`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tools/bazel.rc#L31) but does not defined any `opt` configuration. So setting `--config opt` will do nothing.

ADDENDUM: ./configure of TensorFlow add some C++ options on the .bazelrc on the opt configuration (so it will expand into those C++ options).

Comment: I think after you run ./configure a new .tf_configure.bazelrc is generated which contains an opt configuration

Comment: Indeed as zlalanne is putting in his answer the configure script is setting some C++ options in the local rc file.